# On 18.04.4 HWE yet still have one old 4.15 Kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I have Kubuntu 18.04.4. I Moved to the Hardware Enablement Stack a while back. But still a 4.15 Kernel persists. Can anyone tell me what it is there for?  I do have a bunch of VirtualBox(6.1) installs.  Can one of those require a certain kernel?

```
sudo update-grub

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-61-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-61-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-108-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-108-generic

Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
```

Comment: After updating, the old kernel will remain in your system and is accessible in the **Advanced options for ...** option in the grub2 menu.And VBox 6.1 works in kernel 4.x too . See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.1/user/hostossupport.html).And also it's clear from what you've posted that your default kernel is 5.3

Answer (score 1):

After updating, the old kernels still will be there and there's no point to remove them , since you may have problems using the new ones after updating.The older kernels are still accessible in the **Advanced options for ...** option in the **grub2** menu.And from what you've posted it's clear that the default kernel (i.e the default boot option) in your system is `5.3.0-61-generic`.

And VBox 6.1 is compatible with linux kernel 4.x too :

> It should be possible to use Oracle VM VirtualBox on most systems based on Linux kernel 2.6, 3.x, 4.x or 5.x using either the Oracle VM VirtualBox installer or by doing a manual installation.

Read more about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.1/user/hostossupport.html).

And if for whatever reason you wanted to remove the old ones , you can delete these packages for the **4.x** kernels :

```
linux-headers-VERSION
linux-hwe-tools-VERSION
linux-image-VERSION
linux-modules-VERSION
linux-modules-extra-VERSION
linux-tools-VERSION
```